# Extracting duplicate values where other fields also match

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am using the following query to find duplicate `zip` values in my dataset.

This does work to display the Country, City and Street of any duplicate zip values, but I really want it to only include duplicates if they also have the same country, city and street and not just the zip value?

```
SELECT
  Country,
  City,
  Street,
  zip
FROM
  project.dataset.tablename
WHERE
  zip > 1
  AND CAST(zip AS string) IN (
  SELECT
    CAST(zip AS string)
  FROM
    project.dataset.tablename
  GROUP BY
    CAST(zip AS string)
  HAVING
    COUNT(CAST(zip AS string)) > 1 )
ORDER BY
  zip DESC
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY zip, country, city, street) as cnt
      FROM project.dataset.tablename t
     ) t 
WHERE cnt > 1
ORDER BY zip;
```

In any case, for this type of question, window functions usually provide the best solution.